# Return more than 1 value in Excel table (for calculating total route distance)

Tags: excel, match, distance, lookup

I made this Excel sheet to calculate total distance of a particular route and to keep track of trips. However, it makes many calculations which will eventually make it very slow (even more if routes have many stops).

In the image, **Column P** is the distance between **PLACE_1** and **PLACE_2**, **Column Q** is the distance between **PLACE_2** and **PLACE_3** and so on. **Column O** is the sum of all these distances.

I used `=INDEX(distance_table, MATCH(), MATCH())` to find the distances

[image]

This is the **distance_table** (distances are not real, just an example):

[image]

So as you can see, it works but it is very inefficient, the index/match formula will be used 10 times per trip.

What could be done to improve it? (considering there could be more than 10 stops per trip)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: short of using vba and variant arrays, INDEX/MATCH will be the most performant choice.

Comment: Yeah I thought about VBA, but I believe the code would be a bit difficult for me, many variables come into play. If there is no better/other way using regular formuas, I could give it a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SUM`/`INDEX`/`MATCH`/`MATCH` array formula:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$J$10,N(IF(1,MATCH($A$15:$J$15,$A$2:$A$10,0))),N(IF(1,MATCH($B$15:$K$15,$B$1:$J$1,0)))),0))
```

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly! I had a hard time trying to figure out the formula but now I get it. I didn't know that MATCH could return an array (a value/position for each MATCH).

I noticed that if I remove the "N(IF(1" part, it still works (at least in 365).

The "places" matrix now is like this "0,a,b,c,d,e,f, g, h, i" and the distance from and to "0" is always 0. This way, if a trip has only 4 stops, I can put zeroes in the other columns like this:

Trip 01: "a, d, e, a, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0"

Answer (score 1):

Not intended as an answer. because in terms of [performance](https://exceloffthegrid.com/optimize-formula-calculation-speed-part-7-multi-criteria-lookups/) index/match is faster, just as an alternative and maybe it can give you ideas:

Setup:
[image: Setup]

Formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$6:$B$14=B3)*($C$5:$K$5=C3);$C$6:$K$14) +
SUMPRODUCT(($B$6:$B$14=C3)*($C$5:$K$5=D3);$C$6:$K$14) +
SUMPRODUCT(($B$6:$B$14=D3)*($C$5:$K$5=E3);$C$6:$K$14) +
SUMPRODUCT(($B$6:$B$14=E3)*($C$5:$K$5=F3);$C$6:$K$14) +
SUMPRODUCT(($B$6:$B$14=F3)*($C$5:$K$5=G3);$C$6:$K$14) +
SUMPRODUCT(($B$6:$B$14=G3)*($C$5:$K$5=H3);$C$6:$K$14) +
SUMPRODUCT(($B$6:$B$14=H3)*($C$5:$K$5=I3);$C$6:$K$14) +
SUMPRODUCT(($B$6:$B$14=I3)*($C$5:$K$5=J3);$C$6:$K$14) +
SUMPRODUCT(($B$6:$B$14=J3)*($C$5:$K$5=K3);$C$6:$K$14)
```